# How to properly use a regex for font locking

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock, rx

I'm stuck with a specific problem, I'm writing a `major-mode` for a language that supports multiple assignment, meaning that:

```
let s = 9
let x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
var k = 11
var a, c = 4, 5
```

Are all valid assignments.

I'm trying to write a proper regex with `rx` to deal with that but the result I have right now ends up font-locking the comma as well because it captures everything in a group.

```lisp
(defvar my-font-lock-variable-decl
  `((,(rx symbol-start (or "let" "var")
      (1+ space)
      (group (* (seq (any letter ?_) (* (any word ?_)) (? ?,) (* space)))))
     (1 font-lock-variable-name-face))
  "Font lock keywords to use in `my-mode' for variable declaration."))
```

[image]

I've been reading the code in `python.el` which seems to deal with it but I don't understand how, it has custom macros that I just don't get.

I'd like to obtain the same result as above but without the commas being font-locked.

P.S: This is what's going on in `python.el`, with custom macros. Since it's included with Emacs, one can `C-h f python-mode` and then visit the `python.el` file and search for `python-rx` as well as "multiple assignment".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MATCH-ANCHORED facility of `font-lock-keywords` like so:

```el
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'my-mode
 '(("^\\(\\(?:let\\|var\\) +\\)[a-z]\\sw*\\(?:, *[a-z]\\sw*\\)* ="
    "[a-z]\\sw*"
    (progn (goto-char (match-end 1))
           (match-end 0))
    nil
    (0 font-lock-variable-name-face))))
```

Which is:

- If we match regexp #1:
- Then match every instance of regexp #2 on that same line...
- ...starting from the end of #1's first group
- ...and bounded by end of #1
- Don't do anything afterwards
- Highlight each entire match for #2 as a variable name

(I'll leave you to `rx`ify the regexps.  It was just easier to experiment with standard syntax.)

Comment: Thanks I'll have to play around with it and I'll come back to you asap. I added a screenshot of what's going on in python.el that I'm trying to emulate for reference.

Comment: Good to know, I found `xr`(https://github.com/mattiase/xr) which converts regexes to `rx` syntax, life safer honestly.

Comment: Yeah, `xr` is excellent.  Hopefully that'll be part of Emacs in future.

Comment: For clarity, I wasn't suggesting you should convert my regexps verbatim (they're probably not robust enough, and at minimum I left out the underscores).

Comment: Yep but it's nothing too bad =) I'm struggling with putting it into a defvar to add it to all my other fontifications though. Instead of calling font-lock-add-keywords

Comment: You didn't show how you were using `my-font-lock-variable-decl` so I can't help with that.

Comment: That probably deserves another post as I'm using multiple variables as well as functions to try to get the proper font-locking, I ended up adapting your answer but I'm still not satisfied because the font-locking is a bit jumpy on some edge cases. For example it starts needlessly skipping font-locking over several lines in some cases. I'll probably try to do something else than a major-mode for now, it's been a bit frustrating.